# What are requirements to handler of Push Callback of Foursquare API?

Tags: foursquare

What are requirements for handler of Push Callback of Foursquare API?

- What http verb 4sq uses to make a call ?
- What parameters/information does it send to my server ?
- What my server should reply ?

Surprisingly I don't see answers on these questions at https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/

**Update:**

Well, since nobody replied I decided to insert to DB whatever comes to my end-point. Turned out callbacks never reach my server. Foursquare Push Console says my server returns `502 Bad Gateway` which it doesn't. Is it possible that Foursquare backend ignores port number in callback URL ? My url looks like this

`https://api.hostmane.com:8443/api/handle_4sq_push`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, seems like Foursquare doesn't have anyone from API team responsible for communicating with developers. I sent them email as well but nobody replied.

So here are my findings:

- Foursquare backend doesn't use port number from call-back url. I think it's a **bug**. So make sure you're listening on port 443.
- It's HTTP POST with form-url-encoded parameters.
- There are three parameters passed: `checkin` ([this object](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/responses/checkin) in json), `user` ([this object](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/responses/user.html) in json), `secret` (Push Secret from settings of your app).
- Your server is supposed to reply with error code 200.