# foursquare venue-push api test errors

Tags: python, foursquare

So I am working with the foursquare venue-push api. I have set-up https on my dev server, the auth token seems to be correct. I am getting a 403 Forbidden error which means

> 403 Forbidden:
>
> The requested information cannot be viewed by the acting user, for
>   example, because they are not friends with the user whose data they
>   are trying to read.
>
> Also according to docs: Although authentication succeeded, the acting
>   user is not allowed to see this information due to privacy
>   restrictions.

Now the twist is that I am following everything according to [Foursquare realtime API](https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/realtime).

I am the manager of a venue and I have authenticated the app. The error says that the auth_token is correct but I am not authorized to see the contents. 
Now my questions is that how is the POST response by foursquare api trying to figure my identity? 
I do get a POST on my dev server.
I have also tried to follow the flow given in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17604929/what-are-requirements-to-handler-of-push-callback-of-foursquare-api/17607498#17607498)

I have also tried: venue giving authorization to the app, but it still gives me the same error.
Any help would be appreciated.

PS: I am working on the django framework and the venue endpoint api is working perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer. It was a django thing. needed to exempt csrf, since django requires csrf.